# how can I stop the execution of the while loop with a keyboard input?

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I have several threads. Each thread haves a while(true) loop inside, where I add cycle-by-cycle text. I don't find a good method to change the while(true) loop with a flag, in such a way that I can close the file when I come out from the cycle. I want to do this when I type something for example, or when I press the Eclipse red button.

This is the constructor (**Node** is a Thread)

```
public Node(Channel c, int address) {
    my_address=address;
    try {
        writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(my_address + "_id.csv"), ',', ' ' , ' ' ,"\n");
        writer2 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(my_address + "_label.csv"), ',', ' ' , ' ' ,"\n");
        String[] entries = "num#state#duration#event#condition#condition result#action1#action2#backoff value".split("#");
        writer.writeNext(entries);
        writer2.writeNext(entries);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the loop in which I modify the file:

```
while (true) {
        //write id value
        String id_to_split = num+"#"+fsm.current_state.nome+"#"+tempo_minore+"#"+
                fsm.current_transition.e.getId()+"#"+ fsm.current_transition.c.getId()+"#"+
                fsm.current_transition.c.getFlag()+"#"+fsm.current_transition.a.getId()+"#"+
                fsm.current_transition.a2.getId()+"#"+backoff;

        String[] id_entries = id_to_split.split("#");
        writer.writeNext(id_entries);

        //write name
        String label_to_split = num+"#"+fsm.current_state.nome+"#"+tempo_minore+"#"+
                fsm.current_transition.e.getLabel()+"#"+fsm.current_transition.c.getLabel()+"#"+
                fsm.current_transition.c.getFlag()+"#"+fsm.current_transition.a.getLabel()+"#"+
                fsm.current_transition.a2.getLabel()+"#"+backoff;

        String[] label_entries = label_to_split.split("#");

        writer2.writeNext(label_entries);

        num++;
}
    closeCSVs();
}
```

The method *closeCSVs():*

```
    public void closeCSVs() {
    try {
        writer.close();
        writer2.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code examples.

Comment: How about closing the file after the loop and breaking the loop whenever a certain condition is met? What condition is to be checked and how is up to you. I'd also not open the file stream in the constructor (of the thread?) but right before entering the loop, if that is possible.

Comment: To fix the code to do what you want, you will most likely need to change.

Comment: _or when I pressed the Eclipse red button_ This simply kill the process so there is no clear solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, what you're looking for is either a try-with-resources block which works like following:

```
try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("path")) {
    while(true) {
        //use resources
    }
}
```

You can use this with any Class that implements the AutoClosable-Interface (basically every class that offers a .close()-Method).
The resource will be closed automatically after the try-block is escaped.

Same solution different code would be to wrap with a classic try and adding a finally block to it.

```
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("path");
    while(true) {
        //use resources
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: It is good practice for the first bit of code to also add the finally and close the FileReader there.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus, try-with resources will do it since it is `AutoClosable`

Comment: You are right. I would prefer  the classic try-catch-finally over try with resources anyways since i think is more readable and also I found that it performed way better on I/O. Not sure if that is generally true though.

Comment: I have to write lines on the file, inside the while loop, and I look for a good method to stop the while cycle, for example when I press a key.

Comment: Okay so i think the simplest way for your solution would be a while(flag) loop, the boolean flag initially is true and gets set to false by console input (use a scanner with system.in) and simply put a check for scanner.hasNext() in the while-loop.

Comment: The problem is that in the while-loop, the application waits for input, and I would want to avoid it.

Comment: Threads ! See for multithreading here. One thread for the scanner, one for the loop

Comment: @matejetz Can you please give me an example? You have understood my question.

Comment: @AxelH Can you please give me an example? You have understood my question

Comment: You're right, i forgot that the hasNext()-Method of the Scanner waits for an input.. okay so another idea is to implement a little gui with a button and an ActionListener that sets the flag. You then can stop on clicking the button.

Comment: That would only work if the loop is started from the main thread an not from the GUI thread. So this is still using two thread. The Scanner would be enough.

Comment: @AxelH Please can you show me an example in my code?

Comment: @matejetz I have already thought about this, but I have several threads, so I would have to open an equal number of mini-GUI, that is not a good thing.

Comment: or your flag would be global as well as the gui.

Comment: Well, I can't answer here since your question is closed, but using a flag (the same for each threads) in the while loop, an when each one are running (`.start()`), you simply wait an input on the scanner, `sc.nextLine()` and change the flag value to cleanly stop the loops

Comment: @matejetz and AxelH thanks you for help. I have followed the way pointed out by AxelH and it works

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement closing file in shutdown hook [Runtime.addShutdownHook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))